# Python BeautifulSoup split text after character

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I got the following code returned by BeautifulSoup:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
<li>
  <span class="item">
    <span class="text-bold">
      Company:
    </span>
    Company Name
  </span>
</li>
<li>
  <span class="item">
    <span class="text-bold">
      Location:
    </span>
    Berlin
  </span>
</li>
<li>
  <span class="item">
    <span class="text-bold">
      Country:
    </span>
    Germany
  </span>
</li>
```

Now I want to extract the HTML to output the following Information: Company Name, Berlin & Germany.

How can I implement this?

Comment: I think to *implement this* you should write some code :)  Did you try this solution? Show us how you tried

Answer (score 1):

You can access them by making use of [`.next_sibling`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling) property. Check out the below solution.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content = """
<ul class="list-unstyled">
<li>
  <span class="item">
    <span class="text-bold">
      Company:
    </span>
    Company Name
  </span>
</li>
<li>
  <span class="item">
    <span class="text-bold">
      Location:
    </span>
    Berlin
  </span>
</li>
<li>
  <span class="item">
    <span class="text-bold">
      Country:
    </span>
    Germany
  </span>
</li>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")
for items in soup.select(".text-bold"):
  print(items.next_sibling.strip())
```

Output:

```
Company Name
Berlin
Germany
```